# SPI pins in wifi module module

Tags: wifi

I have a WROOM  WIFI module ..

what are the available SPI pins taken from this IC for communicating?

[DATASHEET](https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/esp32-wroom-32d_esp32-wroom-32u_datasheet_en.pdf)

[image]

Comment: what are the diffrent between HSPI,VSPI?

Answer (score 1):

According to https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/api-reference/peripherals/spi_master.html:

The ESP32 has four SPI peripheral devices, called SPI0, SPI1, HSPI and VSPI. SPI0 is entirely dedicated to the flash cache the ESP32 uses to map the SPI flash device it is connected to into memory. SPI1 is connected to the same hardware lines as SPI0 and is used to write to the flash chip. HSPI and VSPI are free to use. SPI1, HSPI and VSPI all have three chip select lines, allowing them to drive up to three SPI devices each as a master.

[image]